# How to optimzie my function by dropping loops

Tags: r, loops, optimization

I have the following function that uses nested loops and honestly I'm not sure how to proceed with making the code run more efficient. It runs fine for 100 sims in my opinion but when I ran for 2000 sims it took almost 12 seconds.

This code will generate any `n` Brownian Motion simulations and works well, the issue is once the simulation size is increased to say 500+ then it starts to bog down, and when it hits 2k then it's pretty slow ie 12.

Here is the function:

```r
ts_brownian_motion <- function(.time = 100, .num_sims = 10, .delta_time = 1,
                            .initial_value = 0) {

    # TidyEval ----
    T <- as.numeric(.time)
    N <- as.numeric(.num_sims)
    delta_t <- as.numeric(.delta_time)
    initial_value <- as.numeric(.initial_value)

    # Checks ----
    if (!is.numeric(T) | !is.numeric(N) | !is.numeric(delta_t) | !is.numeric(initial_value)){
        rlang::abort(
            message = "All parameters must be numeric values.",
            use_cli_format = TRUE
        )
    }

    # Initialize empty data.frame to store the simulations
    sim_data <- data.frame()

    # Generate N simulations
    for (i in 1:N) {
        # Initialize the current simulation with a starting value of 0
        sim <- c(initial_value)

        # Generate the brownian motion values for each time step
        for (t in 1:(T / delta_t)) {
            sim <- c(sim, sim[t] + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(delta_t)))
        }

        # Bind the time steps, simulation values, and simulation number together in a data.frame and add it to the result
        sim_data <- rbind(
            sim_data,
            data.frame(
                t = seq(0, T, delta_t),
                y = sim,
                sim_number = i
            )
        )
    }

    # Clean up
    sim_data <- sim_data %>%
        dplyr::as_tibble() %>%
        dplyr::mutate(sim_number = forcats::as_factor(sim_number)) %>%
        dplyr::select(sim_number, t, y)

    # Return ----
    attr(sim_data, ".time") <- .time
    attr(sim_data, ".num_sims") <- .num_sims
    attr(sim_data, ".delta_time") <- .delta_time
    attr(sim_data, ".initial_value") <- .initial_value

    return(sim_data)
}
```

Here is some output of the function:

```r
> ts_brownian_motion(.time = 10, .num_sims = 25)
# A tibble: 275 × 3
   sim_number     t       y
   <fct>      <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 1              0  0     
 2 1              1 -2.13  
 3 1              2 -1.08  
 4 1              3  0.0728
 5 1              4  0.562 
 6 1              5  0.255 
 7 1              6 -1.28  
 8 1              7 -1.76  
 9 1              8 -0.770 
10 1              9 -0.536 
# … with 265 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

[image: Example Output of the function visualized]

Comment: @akrun I want to skip parallel and actually implement something like sapply I think I may have a solution in the works

Comment: it gave improvement but my code is now off and producing bad results

Comment: I'm going to close this here as I have now asked it on Code Review as suggested by @zephryl

Comment: Based on the code, I guess you may use vectorized functions like `cumsum` instead of looping to return the sum or if it is recursive, then `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE` or even `accumulate`

Comment: yeah, just having a really hard time conceptualizing it

Comment: @zephryl, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: @TobySpeight thank you, I’ll do that in the future and will review the guide myself.

Comment: You can do it right now using the [edit] link - no need to wait for some unspecified future occasion!

Comment: A line like `sim <- c(sim, sim[t] + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(delta_t)))` makes `sim` one element longer at each iteration. This is called "growing an object" and is one of the worst things you can do for performance. (You do this also with `rbind()`.) See [Chapter 2 of the R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) for a detailed description. If you create the object at it's final size as all 0 or all `NA` and then overwrite the 0s as you go your code will be 100 to 1000 times faster. (Though still not nearly as fast as `sim = cumsum(rnorm(N, 1, sqrt(delta_t))`.)

Comment: that will pretty much always generate an upward trending line though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, if you want speed, you should use `cumsum`. You need to be clear what type of Brownian Motion you want (arithmetic, geometric). For geometric Brownian motion, you'll need to correct the approximation error by adjusting the mean. As an example, the [`NMOF` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF) (which I maintain), contains a function `gbm` that implements geometric Brownian Motion through `cumsum`. Here is an example call for 2000 paths with 100 timesteps each.

```
library("NMOF")
library("zoo") ## for plotting

timesteps <- 100
system.time(b <- NMOF::gbm(2000, tau = 1, timesteps = 100, r = 0, v = 1))
##  user  system elapsed 
## 0.013   0.000   0.013 

dim(b)  ## each column is one path, starting at time zero
## [1]  101 2000

plot(zoo(b[, 1:5], 0:timesteps), plot.type = "single")
```

[image: Brownian Motion]